# Update Function not returning value correctly

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables that I am concatenating fields from. The first table (tbl1Artwork) primary key (ID), has a data type of AutoNumber and a format of "SA"0000. The second table (tbl0Artist), field (ArtistSKU) is formatted as ShortText. I am running the code shown as an AfterUpdate in a form. The expected result is "SA0008DL1" (the DL1 is concatenated from the ArtistSKU field). The actual result is 8DL1. This is confusing as SA0008 is properly stored in the ID field of table tbl1Artwork.

`Option Compare Database
Private Function UpdateArtworkSKU()
    Me.ArtworkSKU = Me.txtArtworkID & Me.cboArtistID.Column(3)
End Function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you have formatted the primary key field to look like "SA0008", the actual value being stored is just 8. You would therefore need to amend the code to read:

`Me.ArtworkSKU = "SA" & Format(Me.txtArtworkID,"0000") & Me.cboArtistID.Column(3)`

As an aside, using the primary key when it is an autonumber for anything other than joining data behind the scenes is normally a bad idea.

Regards,

Comment: Thank you. I understand about limiting the use of the primary key to joining data, but I am creating SKU numbers from different components and this seems to be the best way. I wish there could be more than one AutoNumber field allowed in a single table. The info you provided about the formatting not being stored is helpful.

Comment: I tried the code variation you provided but the result was "SA8DL1". Is there a way to get the formatted primary key into the fold?

Comment: I think that I may have got the fields the wrong way around - I've modified my answer to apply the formatting to ArtworkID.

Comment: That did it. Thanks again @Applecore.